# Align text in JLabel to the right

Tags: java, jpanel, jlabel, text-alignment

I have a JPanel with some JLabel added with the `add()` method of JPanel. I want to align the JLabel to the right like the image below but I don't know how to do that. Any Idea? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Would you like the text of the label align horizontally?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

This can be done in two ways.

**JLabel Horizontal Alignment**

You can use the `JLabel` [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#JLabel%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
JLabel(String text, int horizontalAlignment)
```

To align to the right:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Telephone", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
```

`JLabel` also has `setHorizontalAlignment`:

```
label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
```

This assumes the component takes up the whole width in the container.

**Using Layout**

A different approach is to use the layout to actually align the component to the right, whilst ensuring they do not take the whole width.  Here is an example with `BoxLayout`:

```
    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("test1, the beginning");
    label1.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    box.add(label1);

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("test2, some more");
    label2.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    box.add(label2);

    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("test3");
    label3.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    box.add(label3);


    add(box);
```

Answer (score 10):

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("fax", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 1):

To me,
it seems as if your actual intention is to put different words on different lines.
But let me answer your first question:

```
JLabel lab=new JLabel("text");
lab.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
```

And if you have an image:

```
JLabel lab=new Jlabel("text");
lab.setIcon(new ImageIcon("path//img.png"));
lab.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
```

But, I believe you want to make the label such that there are only 2 words on 1 line.

In that case try this:

```
String urText="<html>You can<br>use basic HTML<br>in Swing<br> components," 
   +"Hope<br> I helped!";
JLabel lac=new JLabel(urText);
lac.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
```