# How do I write text to Graphics2D with justified alignment?

Tags: java, graphics2d

[Using AttributedString and addAttribute()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764890/add-subscripts-and-a-font-to-a-string-in-graphics-on-a-jframe) I can write out a line of formatted text, with the formatting set to sub-ranges of the text.

[Using LineBreakMeasurer.nextLayout().getAdvance()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323701/align-text-to-the-right-in-a-textlayout-using-java-graphics2d-api) I can then both center & right align. (And left align is trivial.)

But how do I tell it to justify it to a left and right margin? I think it's to use [TextAttribute.JUSTIFICATION](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html#JUSTIFICATION) but it's not clear how to use it. It says a range of 0..1 and 1 clearly is no impact, but it's not clear how other settings will cause a spacing out of the text.

Or... am I going about this all wrong? I need to write lines of text (not paragraphs - I handle the line breaks) where the lines of text can have different formatting over sub-ranges of the text. And the line can be left, center, right, or justify aligned.

Comment: Just to add to your research the class FontMetrics (g2d.getFontMetrics()) can help you measure the texts for pixel sizes

Comment: Did you specify a width for you text ? From doc "The default value is 1, indicating that justification should use the full width provided" so maybe your problem is there.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400566/full-justification-with-a-java-graphics-drawstring-replacement?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Lutzi - that example shows how to calculate soft line breaks. But it doesn't (unless I'm missing something) render justified aligned text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The trick is to use TextLayout.getJustifiedLayout()](https://books.google.com/books?id=yhFxiVyd1MgC&pg=PA702&lpg=PA702&dq=java%20graphics2d%20TextAttribute.JUSTIFICATION&source=bl&ots=8SlI4p58-g&sig=5mcaYgKsNZjVFKsYTydm6PmaB_A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1prP7hN3aAhUl4IMKHdA9BoM4FBDoAQhAMAU#v=onepage&q=java%20graphics2d%20TextAttribute.JUSTIFICATION&f=false). That does it - no need for TextAttribute.JUSTIFICATION.