# How do I center a JLabel in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

So I am new in Java, and I want to create a menu. The first thing I have to do is a JLabel with the game name in it. I did everything, but I can't figure out how to center the JLabel to be in the center of the screen, and not on the side

My friend gave me a code, but It doesn't work very well, here it is:

```
public static String gameName = "Game Name Placeholder";
JLabel label = new JLabel(gameName);
        label.setBounds(this.getWidth()/2-100,this.getHeight()/2-150,1000,100);
        label.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 34));

panel.add(label);
add(panel);
```

And here you can see clearly it is not centered:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTeoX.png]

Sorry, I may look dumb. I just started learning Java 2 days ago on my own, so if someone could help me out I would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: You should look into [Java Swing Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and use a layout manager to do the job instead of manually setting the bounds of your components.

Comment: I tried using panel.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); but now the label wont show, did i mess something up? All i did was change that

Comment: I'm going to assume `panel` is a `JPanel` you created. Did you create a new `BorderLayout` and set it on your JPanel? Otherwise this won't work. `JPanel`s default layout is `FlowLayout` as far as I remember.

Comment: For your use case, maybe use a [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html). [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/BoxLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/BoxLayoutDemo.java) is some simple demo code for the same thing you try to do.

Comment: Use `SwingConstants.CENTER` for the second argument when instantiating the `JLabel`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589494/align-text-in-jlabel-to-the-right

Comment: Don't use a null layout!!! The setBounds(...) statement implies that you are trying to manually position components. Don't! Swing was designed to be used with layout manager as has already been suggested. If you still have problems then post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. .